# How to install Ubuntu's Firefox in Linux Mint?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, firefox

I recently migrated my system to Linux Mint from Ubuntu, and am very dissapointed by the Firefox version of Linux Mint. Problems include bookmarks and the lack of autocomplete in the Google search bar (i.e. the one within the browser, at the right side). A re-installation didn't improve anything; on the contrary, things got worst.

These problems were not present in Ubuntu's Firefox, so I was wondering: Is is possible to install Ubuntu's Firefox in Linux Mint?

Comment: As I know Ubuntu's Firefox is a regular Firefox with a custom start page. I don't think they modified it further somehow. At least my Firefox on Arch Linux is pretty the same as it was on Ubuntu.

Comment: Try http://www.systutorials.com/136954/how-to-add-google-to-firefox-in-linux-mint-as-default-search-engine/

Comment: What sort of problems are you experiencing with bookmarks? And what is worse with a reinstall? Some must enable features such as autocomplete.

Comment: @Peschke The auto complete trouble comes from the beginning. After I re-installed it the bookmarks' suggestion system in the URL bar became super slow. More on the bookmarks' issue here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346978/bookmarks-suggestions-are-too-slow-in-firefox

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. I fix Google search suggestions by this way.

Steps:

1. Remove Mint version of Firefox.
2. In directory /etc/apt/preferences.d
   create file firefox.pref (or any other name) with content:

   ```
   Package: firefox firefox-locale-*
   Pin: release o=Ubuntu
   Pin-Priority: 800
   ```
3. Run apt-get update or similar action and install Firefox back. Now it will be always from Ubuntu repository.

If you have newly installed and not updated (!) system, you can skip first step. Just create this file, go to update manager, press "check" button (!) and install updates. Mint version of Firefox will be replaced by Ubuntu version.

Comment: Confirmed working in 2020.