# Bookmarks' suggestions are too slow in Firefox

Tags: linux-mint, firefox, troubleshooting

After re-installing Firefox on my Linux Mint system I have been experiencing some trouble with my bookmarks; namely, when I start typing in the URL bar (the main bar in Firefox, the one on the left side) the bookmarks' suggestions get displayed too slowly.

Some bookmarks are suggested faster than others (which is an already unusual behavior in Firefox), but if I am looking for a very specific bookmark, the suggestion could take up to 10 seconds or more to materialize.

For example, if I type `youtube` in the URL bar, then I get several suggestions almost as I type (I still can notice some delay); but if I type `youtube altitude` it takes like 10 seconds to suggest the bookmarked video `Tobu - Altitude ft. Kamelia`.

As a faithful Firefox user, I can tell you this is a highly unusual behavior; normally, bookmarks get suggested in real time (i.e. with no noticeable delay). Moreover, I am sure the problem is not the high number of bookmarks I have, because I had the exact same number of bookmarks before I removed and re-installed Firefox and the suggestions worked perfectly.

So my question is: what could be happening and how can I fix it?

**NOTE:** Just to make it absolutely clear: my problem is not how slow a bookmarked page gets loaded; my problem is how slow a bookmarked page gets suggested in the URL bar.